# Удаление объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть у меня такой код:

```
[
    {
        "name": "тест",
        "balance": 10,
        "count": 1,
        "users": []
    }
]
```

Когда count достигает нуля (arr.count -= 1) весь объект (name, balance, count, users) нужно удалить. Каким образом можно это сделать?
Получаю я его такой строчкой:

```
const promocode = promo.find(x=> x.name === args[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условия, вам стоит сначала найти индекс элемента, а потом использовать его для удаления:

```js
const promo = [
  { "name": "абв" },
  {
    "name": "тест",
    "balance": 10,
    "count": 1,
    "users": []
  },
  { "name": "эюя" },
];


const promocodeIndex = promo.findIndex(x => x.name === "тест");

const promocode = promo[promocodeIndex];

promocode.count -= 1;
if (promocode.count === 0) promo.splice(promocodeIndex, 1);

console.log(promo);
```